# Sanity check for a declination chart on a QGIS map

Tags: qgis, chart, declination

I'm making a declination chart (True North -> Grid North -> Magnetic North) for a map I plan on using, and I need some sanity check from the community:

The convergence from True to Grid north is 1° (positive east) the declination from True North to Magnetic North is 5° (positive east). If I want to physically orient the map to GN for my plotting, is my GM angle 4 or 6°?

I'm almost sure it is 4°, but some sanity check wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

So I guess I'll answer my own question then...
GM (or GMA) angle indicates only the declination or angular difference
between Grid and Magnetic North. So in my case, it's 4°. If Grid north was west of True & Magnetic North, I would have to add the difference between Grid, True North, and Magnetic North. If Grid North is east of both True North & Magnetic North I'll have to subtract again the difference between Grid & True North.

Edit:
Too bad I can't upvote my own question & answer since they were both useful for me.